# use a URL object to read a resource in web content

Tags: java, url, jsf-2

Im working in a web application using JSF2 and in one of my forms I create a PDF file that contains a image and a specific font. The ressorces are located in the WebContent directory.
My problem is when I want to create the pdf File I want to read the ressources and pass it in parameters to the method creating PDF FILE. I dont know how to use the URL object or any other way to do the task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class has an [`openStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method which gives you an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) of the resource's content:

```
URL resource = externalContext.getResource("/image.png");
InputStream input = resource.openStream();
// ...
```

You can also immediately get the [resource as stream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) without getting it as `URL` first:

```
InputStream input = externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/image.png");
// ...
```

Having the `InputStream`, you can just read it into whatever target object which your PDF creator is expecting as input.

Answer (score 1):

> The ressorces are located in the WebContent directory.

WebContent directory is just for development environment under eclipse. When deployed the files there would go into the root of the web-app. So I take it that you want to access files in the root of your web-app.

You can use `ServletContext.getResource(String path)` with a path as "/myFileName" where the / signifies the web-app context root.

To get the reference to the `ServletContext` you may try [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@shale.apache.org/msg01707.html)